# how to get manager email id in Workflow designer from the people picker column?

Tags: workflow, designer

I am using this code to get the manager email id.But i am not able to get the email id.
Get **Manager/EMail** from Variable: CompletedDataResponse (Output to Variable: ManagerName )

can u please help me out to solve this issue?!

Comment: http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/01/18/how-to-retrieve-users-manager-in-sharepoint-designer-workflows-aspx/

Answer (score 1):

Just try this one , if you are using O365 and SPD2013

1. Open SPD2013 and your workflow
2. Select "Lookup manager for a user"  from the Relational Actions which is under Action Menu.
   This will basically store the Manager of a user in a variable and you can use the variable to do an insert or update to the columns or even ending emails too
3. Lets say current Item: Created By (output to  Variable:ManagerName)

check the Manager name variable to get the current manager name

Hope this helps

Regards,
Vinu Nair

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010 there is an action "Lookup Manager for a User" action.

In SharePoint 2013 you have to use the "Call HTTP Web Service" action.

The request url would be as follows

```
<<site url>>/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v=%27i:0%23.f|membership|<<login>>%27
```

You will get the Manager Info from user properties as follows

```
data.d.UserProfileProperties.results
```

In the results you have to find the Key == Manager and get Value of the property.

Let me know if you need additional information.